# iOS Swift 3 CoreData saving only latest data

Tags: ios, core-data, swift3

I've tried to save some data to core data but when i retrieve the data, i can get only the last saved element.

```
let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Image> = Image.fetchRequest()
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {

    let handler = CoreDataHandler.sharedInstance.managedObjectContext()

    do {
        //go get the results

        let add = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Image", into: handler) as! Image
        let homeData = TimeLineModel()

        homeData.image = urlString
        homeData.audio = ""
        homeData.text = ""
        self.homeDataModel.append(homeData)

        homeTableView.reloadData()
        // self.getLocationName()
        add.image_name = imageName
        add.date_taken = NSDate()
        add.image_path = urlString
        add.longitude = self.imageLat!
        add.latitude = self.imageLong!
        do {
            let searchResults = try handler.fetch(fetchRequest)
            print ("num of results = \(searchResults.count)")
            for trans in searchResults as [NSManagedObject] {
                print("\(trans.value(forKey: "image_name"))")
            }
        } catch {
            print("Error with request: \(error)")
        }

    }
    let fetchRequest:NSFetchRequest<Image> = Image.fetchRequest()
    do {
        let searchResults = try handler.fetch(fetchRequest)
        for trans in searchResults {
            print(trans.image_name!)
        }
        let result = try handler.fetch(fetchRequest)
        print(result)

    }
    catch {
    }

} else {
    // Fallback on earlier versions
}
```

For saving the data

```
let managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext()
let imageInsert = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Image", into: managedObjectContext) as! Image
imageInsert.image_name = getImage(pickedImage: imageData)
imageInsert.date_taken = NSDate()

do {
    saveContext()
}
```

This is the code I use to save and retrieve data, i'm rookie to both development and iOS development so please help me...

Comment: Do you call save on the `managedObjectContext` (in your code `handler`) after you insert the item?

Comment: yes i do @JonRose i've edited the question please take a look...

Comment: why are you inserting an object in `fetchRequest`? and where is the variable `fetchRequest` that is use in the line ` let searchResults = try handler.fetch(fetchRequest)` defined?

Comment: formatted for legibility

Comment: what is this line suppose to be doing: `let add = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Image", into: handler) as! Image`?